# How to access a docker container from the public ip of a server

Tags: docker, nginx, deployment, web, droplet

I'm trying to use docker to deploy my website on a server. I have a droplet with centOS and docker installed on it. When I try to RUN a container (https://hub.docker.com/r/richarvey/nginx-php-fpm/) I was expecting to access my website through my browser using the public IP (ipv4), but I think it's not enough.

What's the problem?

Comment: What steps did you take when you started the container? Can you access it from the server on `127.0.0.1`? I'm guessing the port isn't exposed on the public IP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish the containers ports to the host. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports for details:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 richarvey/nginx-php-fpm
```